# SetState in a Conditional statement inside JSX in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to set my state inside JSX expression and show my component if the condition is true. I tried this this:

```js
const ProductsList = () => {
  const [currenMonth, setCurrenMonth] = useState('');
  const renderItem = (month) => {
        if (currenMonth !== month) {
          setCurrenMonth(month);
          return <Item name={getMonthFromString(month)} active />;
        }
        return null;
      };
  return(
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <FlatList
            data={products}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              return (
                <View>
                  { renderItem(item.orderDate) }
                </View>
              );
            }}
     />
   </View>
  );
}
```

My `Item` Component is :

```js
export default class Item extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    const {
      active,
      name,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={active ? [styles.text, styles.active] : styles.text}>{name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

But i'm getting an Error `[Unhandled promise rejection: Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.]`

The result i have now :
[image: current result]

The result i want to achieve is :
[image: final result]

Comment: setting state causes a render to happen and setting state during a render will cause it to render again so it will just infinitely loop.

you want to call that function in a `useEffect` inside of the `Item` component, not inside of the body that's rendering

Comment: you can not manipulate state like this inside the component, 
whenever state changes component is re-rendered so its just stuck in infinite re-rendering,

Answer (score 2):

you can not manipulate state like this inside the component,
whenever state changes component is re-rendered so its just stuck in infinite re-rendering,

i suggest call useEffect in item component and pass month as a prop.

useEffect will can run the code everytime month is changed

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (month) {
  //do something here
  }
 }, [month])
```

Comment: My `Item` Component is a class. Should i do it in `componentDidUpdate` ?

Comment: yes, componentDidUpdate(prevProps), here you can compare previous props and current props, if different do the needfull

Comment: i'm a little bit lost..What will i do in `componentDidUpdate ` inside `Item` component and how will i update the state `currenMonth ` in `ProductsList` ?

Comment: you can pass call back and currentMonth as a prop, so <Item currentMonth={currentMonth} month={month} updateCurrentMonth={(mon) =>setCurrentMonth(mon)} />

then inside componentDidUpdate of Item, componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
if (prevProps.month !== this.props.month) {
this.props.updateCurrentMonth(this.props.months)
}
}

Comment: why do you even need to update month in state?

Comment: My purpose is to show `Item` component only if the month changes so i thought i would need it. Or should i stock the `currentMoth` inside Item ?

Comment: remove setCurrenMonth(month) in your current code and check

Comment: I still have the same result. Please check my post i've put the result i want to achieve

Comment: ok, i understand now, tell me one more thing, item.orderDate is date or month?

Comment: Yes It's a month

Comment: i added another answer check

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```js
const ProductsList = () => {
  const [currentMonth, setCurrentMonth] = useState('');
  
  return(
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <FlatList
            data={products}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              if (currentMonth !== item.month) {
                setCurrentMonth(item.month);
                return <Item name={getMonthFromString(item.month)} active />;
              }
              return null;
            }}
     />
   </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for Item component

```js
<Item
    currentMonth={currentMonth}
    updateCurrentMonth={() => {
      setCurrentMonth(month)
    }}
    name={currentMonth !== month ? getMonthFromString(month) : ""}
    active
/>
```

```js
const ProductsList = () => {
  const [currenMonth, setCurrenMonth] = useState('');
  const renderItem = (month) => <Item
    currentMonth={currentMonth}
    updateCurrentMonth={() => {
      setCurrentMonth(month)
    }}
    name={currentMonth !== month ? getMonthFromString(month) : ""}
    active
/>
  return(
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <FlatList
            data={products}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
              return (
                <View>
                  { renderItem(item.orderDate) }
                </View>
              );
            }}
     />
   </View>
  );
}
```

as your item component is class

```js
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.updateCurrentMonth()
}
```

Comment: `updateCurrentMonth()` inside `Item` Component what should it be ?

Comment: this.props.updateCurrentMonth(), i passed a call back from parent component, check, so, just call it in componentWillMount

Comment: i got an Error saying that `this.props.updateCurrentMonth()` is not defined

Comment: this.props.updateCurrentMonth()  not "this.this.props.updateCurrentMonth()"

Comment: Yes sorry just a typo `this.props.updateCurrentMonth()`. i'm getting the error `TypeError : this.props.updateCurrentMonth() is not function (In 'this.props.updateCurrentMonth()', 'this.props.updateCurrentMonth()' is undefined)`

Comment: does you Item component inside parent looks like this?
<Item
    currentMonth={currentMonth}
    updateCurrentMonth={() => {
      setCurrentMonth(month)
    }}
    name={currentMonth !== month ? getMonthFromString(month) : ""}
    active
/>

Comment: Yes and my `Item` component is 
`export default class Item extends PureComponent {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.updateCurrentMonth();
  }

  render() {
    const {
      active,
      name,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={active ? [styles.text, styles.active] : styles.text}>{name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}`

Comment: you can add me to you repo, i can see. nikhilb2 my github

Comment: product list should look like as in updated answer